# IRS Form W4-P : Should I remain aligned with the current version of this form?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, pension

I got a note in the mail from a pension administrator company on behalf of a former employer. I only worked at this employer for a month in 2022, and about $300 was put in a pension fund for me. Upon leaving my position, I received a check for the $300 from this pension administrator company.

This note says that "Our records indicate that you currently have Federal tax withheld on your recurring payment. the IRS has updated their W4-P form Withholding Certificate for Pension or Annuity Payments. One significant change is the removal of the designation of Number of Exemptions claimed. To remain aligned with the current version of the IRS form W-4P, please complete the enclosed W-4P form and send..."

Do I need to do this? I am not receiving any recurring payment from the pension fund at this point - because I was given and cashed a check for the $300 that was put in my pension during the month that I worked there.

If someone could explain this to me that would be great because I do not understand what this form is, and why any of this concerns me.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did they have you sending the form? This sounds like scam.

Comment: @keshlam - They have me sending it to "PenChecks Trust Company of America" in the note they claim that "Name of Former Employer Salaried or Their Third-Party Administrator has contacted PenChecks to process your recurring retirement payment"

Comment: Check with your ex-employer to be 100% sure, but this is now screaming scam to me. Seems to be the season; we are seeing a LOT of spam questions right now.

Comment: Honestly - I was thinking the same. Thank you so much for writing back to me, I appreciate it.

Comment: The registry information for penchecks.com isn't as obviously suspicious as some recent ones have been; it claims to have been started in 1999. And there are mentions of them on the web. And per https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-w-4-p, the form is supposed to be sent to the pension administrator.  So this _may_ be legitimate. If your previous employer is still in business, I'd say it's worth checking with them to confirm who is administering their pensions and that they have subcontracted to PenChecks. I had to do a similar dance when my student loan was resold without advance notice.